# What is the proper way to use a list for vector in r for the multiple parameter portion of a function call?

Tags: r

Let us saw we have a function defined as:

```
foobar(string.argument, ...)
```

let us say we have a list

```
my.list <- list("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

how can we invoke foobar equivalent to:

```
foobar("some value", "a", "b", "c", "d")
```

of course using my.list for the variable parameter list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do.call` would probably help you do what you want:

```
my.list <- list("a", "b", "c", "d")
#add 'some value' to my.list
my.list <- c('some value', my.list)

do.call(foobar, my.list)
```

`do.call` will run foobar having as arguments the elements in my.list.